# What is alternative in angular for href present in html?

Tags: html, angular, href

I want to define const url in component.ts file so that I can test it and access this url in html file.There are some solutions to use ngHref but it is not working in my case. How can I define comst url in component.ts file and ccess in html file. Here is my html code

```
    <a [ng-href]="{{href}}" {{href}} target="_blank">Show</a>
```

Here is my component.ts file

```
export class Table implements OnInit {
  public href = `www.yahoo.com
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
public myLink = "https://yahoo.com";
…
<a [href]="myLink" target="_blank">Show</a>
```